# ReadOnly Property Gets "Unintentional" Change

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, oop

I understand that List, Array, Object etc. types "copied" by reference. However my natural and ordinary intend is to just have a "copy" of it in this context where I intentionally use ReadOnly instead of Read/Write property. In below sample the ReadOnly 'Extensions' property get change through 'm_extensions' reference change. Regardless, I think this behavior is incorrect and I have to do extra work to prevent ReadOnly properties from being overwritten. Is there any built in keyword to use for 'm_extensions' value protection?

```
Public Classs A

    ' more properties and methods here...

    Private m_extensions() As String = {"*.abc", "*.def"}
    Public ReadOnly Property Extensions() As String()
        Get
            Return m_extensions
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Public Classs B

    ' more stuff here...

    Private Function BuildFilter() As String
        Dim l() As String = A.Extensions
        Dim s As String = String.Empty
        For m As Integer = 0 To l.Length - 1
            Select Case l(m).ToLower
                Case "*.*" : s = "All Files"
                Case "*.abc" : s = "ABC File"
                Case "*.def" : s = "DEF File"
                Case Else : s = "XYZ File " + m.ToString
            End Select
            l(m) = String.Format("{1} ({0})|{0}", l(m), s)
        Next
        Return String.Join("|", l)
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

`Readonly` modifier means that anything using the property cannot change the reference that you protected this way (e.g. cannot set it to Nothing). It doesn't prevent changing the values in the array returned from that property.

One way around it could be to copy the array inside the property. This will prevent modifications of the original array:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Extensions() As String()
    Get
        Return m_extensions.Clone()
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks Szymon, though I still wonder why there is a "fake" ReadOnly label if 50% of cases is not ReadOnly at all ;)

Comment: Well, it guarantees that the reference cannot be affected.